# Getting gray instead of white when recording screen activity

Tags: video, video-recording, h.264, nvenc

I am recording from screen

[image: source]

however, the video when recording with a recording program, (screen around cursor mode) gets grayish

[image: recorded]

why?

Video settings are H264 - NVENC (VBR)
30 fps, 100q

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this was a VLC problem. Its the playback of the video recording that has got darkened!

The left program is "Film & TV" provided by windows.

If I in VLC was unchecking the option "use hardware conversions YUV -> RGB", the playback was not washed out anymore. Describe in https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:Video:Color_washed_out/.

[image: comparision]